# How to remove all traces of a deleted WPF UserControl?

Tags: wpf

I created a UserControl called FilterButton in my skins folder by accident.  After deleting the XAML and creating it again in the correct (root) directory I find that I cannot change the base class because the compiler is still seeing the old FilterButton and treating it as a partial class.

How do I remove all references to the deleted control?  I deleted all obviously related files in my obj/Debug folder, did a clean & rebuild of the solution, and there appears to be no reference to that class anywhere in my code, yet the problem persists.

Is deleting the ENTIRE contents of the obj/Debug folder a possible solution, or will this cause other issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this problem, I discovered that the XAML file needed to change the relevant tag to the changed class type in the code behind.  I was unaware that the class reference in the XAML file was considered a "partial class" so I wasn't even looking there.